# Image button that is sized in percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, button

i'm trying to implement something like a door bell in a webpage. I have a background image of a door inside a div and I want to add an image of a doorbell that is clickable. I would also like to change the image in the button when it is currently clicked.

I tried using image buttons techniques i've found on the web which uses something like this:

```
<a id="bell" class="button" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

the anchor tag has a background property in the CSS which is the button image. But I cannot resize it with percentages. I want the door and door bell to resize according to page percentage. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

anchor elements aren't block level elements by default, if you set css on your anchor elements to display:block; you'll be able to its size in %. That said, without seeing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's difficult to give the best guidance - remember to ensure your mark up is semantically correct as 'button' elements may be more appropriate over anchor elements.

Comment: but I cannot change the size of the background url that I set to the anchor element. That's what I need to resize.  I used background-size but it doesn't work in FireFox. I just want to have an image button that is resized based on percentages. And that I would be able to change the image on the button when it is currently pressed and when released.